# GitLab runs 502 exception in low configuration server

Tags: gitlab

I made the following configuration in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb, but the strange thing is that GitLab appears 502 in a very regular way, about once every 10 minutes

```
external_url 'https://example.com'
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = ['127.0.0.1','localhost']
gitlab_rails['terraform_state_enabled'] = false
gitlab_rails['usage_ping_enabled'] = false
gitlab_rails['redis_host'] = "127.0.0.1"
gitlab_rails['redis_port'] = 6379
gitlab_rails['sentry_enabled'] = false
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:7991"
puma['worker_processes'] = 0
puma['min_threads'] = 1
puma['max_threads'] = 3
puma['port'] = 7992
puma['per_worker_max_memory_mb'] = 512
sidekiq['max_concurrency'] = 5
postgresql['shared_buffers'] = "512MB"
postgresql['max_worker_processes'] = 2
redis['enable'] = false
nginx['enable'] = false
gitlab_ci['gitlab_ci_all_broken_builds'] = false
gitlab_ci['gitlab_ci_add_pusher'] = false
gitlab_rails['gitlab_kas_enabled'] = false
gitlab_kas['enable'] = false
mattermost['enable'] = false
mattermost_nginx['enable'] = false
prometheus_monitoring['enable'] = false
gitlab_rails['kerberos_enabled'] = false
sentinel['enable'] = false
```

This is the puma log, it looks like it just keeps restarting

```
{"timestamp":"2023-09-15T06:07:21.400Z","pid":2590149,"message":"- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish"}
=== puma startup: 2023-09-15 14:08:15 +0800 ===
{"timestamp":"2023-09-15T06:13:54.109Z","pid":2591848,"message":"- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish"}
=== puma startup: 2023-09-15 14:14:32 +0800 ===
{"timestamp":"2023-09-15T06:20:10.861Z","pid":2593485,"message":"- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish"}
=== puma startup: 2023-09-15 14:20:48 +0800 ===
```

Since my configuration is very low, the default configuration cannot start properly, what should I do? I need everyone's help, thanks.

Comment: I have a good experience on Gitlab installations, but I need the full log to help you.